# Accessing "From:" from VBA in Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook

I have on account "me@domain.com" configured in Outlook 2010.  I compose a message and open the drop-down on "From:".  I select "Other email address..." and type in "bingo@bongo.com".  I get a pop-up asking whether to send messages from "bingo@bongo.com" via the "me@domain.com" account.  I "ok" that.  When I now send a message to "someone@domain.com", the recipient sees

From: bingo@bongo.com

Curiously, when I go to inspect me@domain.com/Sent Items, all I see is

From: me@domain.com

I am very frustrated about this behaviour because I wish to move sent items depending on the sending account.  Initially I looked into creating a Send Rule.  Irritatingly, there is no option to action anything based on "From:".  So I dive into VBA.  I got most of the code to move the stuff, but when I look through the mail item object (in the Locals window), I cannot find any property that states "bingo@bongo.com".

Can anyone advise how to extract the Reply-To (I guess it is) address from the outgoing mail item?

It is quite bizarre that an Outlook recipient of this email will see

From: me@domain.com sent on behalf of bingo@bongo.com

but the SendOnBehalf property in the Outlook mail item simply reads "me@domain.com".

Any advice much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I would have guessed you could find it in `mailobject.Sender` or `mailobject.ReplyRecipients` (a collection). What do they say?

Comment: Thanks.  Sender says "me@domain.com" and ReplyRecipients has no items at all, rather surprisingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting SentOnBehalf like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetSentOnBehalf()

Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(0)

objMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "bingo@bongo.com"

objMsg.Display

MsgBox " SentOnBehalfOfName in the From: " & objMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName

Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```